# (Android) Не отображается содержимое Toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar

Всем привет.

На трех предыдущих активити все работает как надо, у Toolbar отображается заголовок и пункт меню. Однако в одном из активити отображается только область toolbar'a , заголовок не отображается, меню не отображается, `setTitle()` не работает, `getTitle()` выбрасывает из приложение с сообщением о нулевом объекте.

Подскажите, где недочет?

Код проблемного активити:

```
    public class masterDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ArrayList<response> responseList;
        private ListView lvResponse;
        private Toolbar toolbar;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_master_details);
            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolBar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            ...
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Файл манифеста:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="ru.**">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base"
        tools:replace="@android:icon">

        ...

        <activity
            android:name=".masterDetails"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_master_details">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="ru.qwerq.qwerq.catalog_activity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Файл styles.xml :

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent = "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

И, пожалуй, menu_main.xml :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

UPD

Файл activity_master_details.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="ru.qwerq.qwerq.masterDetails">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/include3" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/zoomPortfolioImage"
        android:src="@drawable/noavatar"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/include2" />
...
```

Comment: Скорее всего у вас toolbar null, т.к. его нет в разметке

Comment: Спасибо за наводку! Toolbar в разметке был, но тэг 
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/include2" />
содержал то что вы видите. Удалил android:id="@+id/include2" и все отображается как нужно

Comment: Видимо, я поторопился. Тут какая то гизма происходит из-за relative layout. Если убрать строчку android:id="@+id/include2" из тэга <include/> , то в тулбаре меню и заголовок отображаются, но остальные элементы налезают на него. Если остальные элементы опустить вниз, то, естесственно им нужно от чего то отталкиваться, и студия сама добавляет android:id="@+id/include2". Как сохранить овец и при этом волков накормить?

Comment: Есть несколько вариантов. Попробуйте инклюду ID проставить такой же, как у тулбара в нём

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в данном случае в том, что проставленный тегу `include` ID перекрывал ID тулбара, коий подключался через `include`.

Решить это можно проставив для `include` такой же ID как и у тулюара, т.е. - `toolbar`